# Small self-contained email datasets

Tags: research, email, visualization

For a research article, I am currently looking for a small, self-contained email dataset.

The reason I'm saying small, is because many email datasets I've found so far contain a large amount of emails. Examples include the [Enron dataset](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~enron/) (about 500 thousand emails), the [Jeb Bush dataset](https://github.com/hical/sample-dataset) (290 thousand emails), and the [Hillary Clinton dataset](https://wikileaks.org/clinton-emails/) (30 thousand emails).

For the purposes of the research I'm conducting, I need much smaller e-mail datasets. One of the things I could do I extract a small sample from these larger datasets, but then coherence between and theme among these messages might be lost somewhat.

I am therefore looking for self-contained, small, English, public datasets consisting of at most 50 emails, preferably even smaller (around 25 emails). The idea behind the research project is to formulate a model that can describe the different relations between such emails (both their metadata and their textual contents), and to illustrate this model with a visualization of the emails and the relations among them (topical, causal, entity-based, etc.).

What I mean by self-contained is that the e-mails sent and received within a certain period don't have any follow-up e-mails after that period on that case or topic. So it's a collection of e-mails that is sort of sealed off, the case is closed so to speak.

**Question**: are there any self-contained, public, English datasets that consist of fewer than 50 emails?